# Why in this definition of Riemann integral isn't required that the mesh gets smaller?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Why in this definition for the Riemann integral, taken from wikipedia page for it, isn't explicitly required that the mesh gets smaller? Because a refinement of a partition doesn't require that the mesh gets smaller. That means that I can keep one interval the same width and refine the other part.

> For all $ε > 0$, there exists a tagged partition $y_0, ..., y_m$ and
>   $r_0, ..., r_{m − 1}$ such that for any tagged partition $x_0, ..., x_n$
>   and $t_0, ..., t_{n − 1}$ which is a refinement of $y_0, ..., y_m$ and
>   $r_0, ..., r_{m − 1}$, we have
>
> $${\displaystyle \left|\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(t_{i})(x_{i+1}-x_{i})-s\right|<\varepsilon .}$$

Comment: What is the definition of $s$ in this context?

Comment: The value of the integral, the limit.

Comment: That's not entirely correct. The number $s$ is defined by the above property if it is satisfied. Notice that from this definition it is not immediately clear that $s$ is uniquely defined if it exists! (You'll have to use that any two tagged partitions have a common refinement).

Comment: May you elaborate please on how this is not correct? If we don't define $s$ as the value of the integral (the limit of the sum) than how can we use it in the expression? Or you are referring to the uniqueness of the number $s$? If it is the second case, than what is wrong with defining $s$ to be the value of the integral and than prove that that number is unique? Thanks.

Comment: If you follow the wiki page, the Riemann integral $s$ of a function $f$ is defined by the above property (and thus not as a limit, where do you see $s=\lim \dots$?). One can show that this definition is equivalent to the usual limit definition (basically you are taking a limit over all partitions).

Comment: Yes, you are right, the number $s$ in this case is defined by the property above, but since this is equivalent to a limit definition we can rephrase the definition like this $\begin{align} \quad \int_a^b f(x) \: dx = s= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(x_k^*) \Delta x \end{align}$ and it is the same thing. Is this ok? Or we actually need to show that this is a limit definition? Because I see the integral defined as a limit in a lot of places, like the equation i posted above.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that it has to hold for **any** refinement, including those where you do make the mesh smaller and smaller.

Comment: How are the $t_i$s relevant to that the mesh gets smaller? A refinement is basically a new set of points where we can find the other set of points we want to refine plus some others.

Comment: Ah ok I misunderstood your question. I'll edit the answer!